# google speech recognition api in hindi

Tags: c#, voice-recognition, speech, hindi, google-voice-search

I am looking for a Google Speech Recognition API, but I was not able to find any. Google has started service of Hindi Speech Recognition, as an example:- If I say "Kahan jaa rahe ho", then it searches for "Kahan jaa rahe ho" which means it converts speech to text. All I want is that my app should recognize what I say and give that Hinglish Text as output. Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this or any link to documentation, I've already checked an online service (https://dictation.io). I want to implement the same in my app.

Comment: Check out the following links- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148373/how-to-use-google-speech-recognition-api-in-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049507/google-speech-to-text-api-in-c-sharp

Comment: https://gist.github.com/satana/75e639434b66e6c62e18

Comment: This seems to contain a working example - https://googlespeechtotext.codeplex.com

Comment: Were you able to work it out using the links which I provided? If yes, then I can post as an answer, which you can then accept. Let me know :)

Comment: @ManikArora yes, it is working fine. U can also upvote my question..

Comment: If possible can you post the part of your code in which you implemented the google speech recognition api, it might help others as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the following links- [How to use google speech recognition api in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148373/how-to-use-google-speech-recognition-api-in-c)

[Google speech to text API in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049507/google-speech-to-text-api-in-c-sharp)

https://gist.github.com/satana/75e639434b66e6c62e18

This seems to contain a working example - https://googlespeechtotext.codeplex.com/